# I am looking to record recent ip's logging into the system

Tags: php

```
//collect form data
$user = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$rec_ip = $_POST['rec_ip']; // <---

//check if user exist in the database
$sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";

//create SQL UPDATE statement
$sqlUpdate = "UPDATE users SET rec_ip =:rec_ip WHERE id =:id"; // <---
$statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
$statement->execute(array(':username' => $user));
```

This is how i'm recording the IP's:

```
<input type="hidden" 
        class="form-control 
        margin-bottom-20" 
        name="rec_ip" 
        value="<?php $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; echo $ip; ?>"
        >
```

The thing i don't get is everything seems to be going to plan (no errors)
apart from the fact it won't update the Recent ip...

==========================UPDATED METHOD==========================

How about

```
    //collect form data
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $rec_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


    //check if user exist in the database
    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :username";

   $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO users WHERE (reg_ip)
      VALUES ('$rec_ip')";

    $statement = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
    $statement->execute(array(':username' => $user));
```

would this method work?

Comment: you didn't add the 2nd bind to the array

Comment: nor does that `:username` correspond

Comment: Where are you preparing and executing your second query? And getting the id from the first one? And why would you allow the user to manipulate the ip address, there is no need to send it to the form to send it back to the server again.

Comment: so would you suggest keeping it as -> $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  ?

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a typo error its **reg_ip** in form and **rec_ip** on your PHP script. Might this be the issue?

Comment: typo on my part entering it onto this site sorry i have it set as reg_ip for registration ip's sorry